# Google Feed Parser Missing Properties (nodes)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, json, rss

So, what I want to do seems pretty simple. I have an RSS Feed which is http://men.hfbcpodcast.com/All_In_Retreat_Podcast/podcast.xml. I am using Google's Feed service that you can check out here [Returned Google Feed](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=100&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=http://men.hfbcpodcast.com/All_In_Retreat_Podcast/podcast.xml).

The problem that I am facing is that the returned feed is ignoring lots of information such as itunes:duration and loads of other stuff. What is going on here? Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

So, it makes me sad that I had to go this route, but I ended up using https://github.com/jfhovinne. I was trying to go an angular-only approach, but using jQuery and a bit of the code provided did the fix. One thing to note, jQuery had a tough time finding "itunes:duration", so instead of

```
jQuery(this).find('itunes:duration').eq(0).text();
```

use

```
this.getElementsByTagName('itunes:duration')[0].innerText;
```

...Inside the JRss._parse method